# Opening a browser intent forcing it to use a specific network interface

Tags: android, networking

Following problem - I'm working on an app which supports the user with router and repeater configuration via various APIs. But in some cases we need to open the WebUI of the device, which 
turns out to be a problem when I'm connected to a WiFi which has no internet access, but the phone also has working mobile internet.

In my special case I want to set up a WiFi repeater. The repeater is in factory-reset state, and I'm connected via WiFi to it. When I now try to open the browser with the repeater's URL, the browser uses the mobile connection and is not possible to open the address. If I turn off mobile internet, it works.

Any chance to get it working without deactivating mobile internet?

Comment: AFAIK, you would need to render the Web content in your own app (e.g., using `WebView`) and hope that you can control what network interface it uses (e.g., using `bindProcessToNetwork()` on `ConnectivityManager`).

An app has no way of forcing an arbitrary other app to use any particular network interface, for obvious privacy and security reasons.

Comment: Thx. That confirms my suspect, that WebView is the only alternative